# Tables in Accordion make responsiv

Tags: html, css, responsive

I would like to make the tables in the accordion responsive on the following page "www.harem-kebap.at"
The function Flex wrap: wrap I've tried it without success.

Thanks for your helping.
Greets

[Normal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WNW07.png)
[Responsiv](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jJmW2.png)

Comment: It would be helpful if you added the code that illustrates the issue, that way people can maybe see/understand the problem without having to make lots of guesses on what "might" be wrong.

Comment: @VishalPatil i have edited my post with Screenshoots

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}


.column {
  float: left;
  width: 33.33%;
  padding: 10px;
  }

.row:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .column {
    width: 100%;
  }
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
th,
td {
 
  padding: 10px 15px;
}
th {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="column">
   <h2>Salad</h2>
    <table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col" colspan="1">Item</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>AA</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>BB</td>    
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>CC</td>     
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>DD</td>      
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  
</table>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <h2>Fingerfood</h2>
     <table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col" colspan="1">Item</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>AA</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>BB</td>    
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>CC</td>     
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>DD</td>      
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  
</table>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <h2>Schnitzel</h2>
    <table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col" colspan="1">Item</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>AA</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>BB</td>    
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>CC</td>     
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>DD</td>      
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  
</table>
  </div>
</div>
```